# HD wallet (bip32) addresses derivation path

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I am creating an application that needs to generate a new address from a provided `XPUB` key.

For instance `xpub6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz`

I am using the Electrum wallet and a key provided by this app.

My application allows users to add their own xpub keys, so my application will be able to generate new addresses without affecting users privacy, as far as `xpub` keys are only used by my application and not exposed to public.

So  I am looking for a way to generate new addresses correctly, I have found some libraries, however I am not sure about the derivation path, how should it look like ?

Consider the following path example

[image]

1. Is the derivation path is more a convention rather than a rule?
2. `Bitcoin first   external    first   m / 44' / 0' / 0' / 0 / 0` is this is a valid path? I have found it here https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki
3. I have also found out that Electrum wallets uses another schema https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/what-bip32-derivation-path-does-electrum-use/36956 in the following format. It uses m/0/ for receiving addresses, and m/1/ for change addresses.
4. What is the maximum number (n) of addresses? How online tools calculate the balance of an HD wallet, if the N number is quite large it will require a lot of processing power to calculate sum.

So all in all, I wonder what format of the derivation path should I use in order to have no problems with compatibility?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

question 1-3: 
It's bip44 convention, electrum isn't following it therefore it's not compatiable with other wallets which support bip44.

question 4: 
the number can be infinite, if you are talking about the maximum number for a certain parent key, answer is:

> Each extended key has 2^31 normal child keys, and 2^31 hardened child
>   key
>   -https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki

if your application design leads to a very large quantity of addresses, that's your own issue which you need to handle it by better design, and if you mean the compatibility with other wallets, according to bip44,

> Address gap limit is currently set to 20. If the software hits 20
>   unused addresses in a row, it expects there are no used addresses
>   beyond this point and stops searching the address chain.
>   https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#Address_gap_limit